# Correct way to terminate a TNetHTTPClient get request with a live stream

Tags: delphi, httpclient

I have a thread which uses a TNetHTTPClient component to get data from a live camera stream. Note that the camera only takes images when it detects motion, so the stream is not continuous. The HTTPClient calls **get** passing a memory stream (MSImage). The event handler for OnReceiveData processes the streamed data and extracts the images from it. That part is all working correctly.

I was not sure how to terminate the **get** when the application shuts down. I have tried using asynchronous and synchronous mode. My code below shows the async option in which I use a repeat-until loop to keep the Execute method running until the thread is terminated.

The OnReceiveData event handler has a paramater called AAbort. If I set this to true the application closes correctly. However as the streamed data is not constant, there is no guarantee that this event will be called at the time the application is closed.

The code I have shown below does work, but causes a memory leak when the application shuts down. The leak appears to be whatever data is in the memory stream at the time it closes.

What is the correct way to break the **get** call?

```
procedure TReadThread.Execute;
var
  HTTPClient: TNetHTTPClient;
begin
  inherited;
  HTTPClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  HTTPClient.Asynchronous := True;
  HTTPClient.OnReceiveData := HTTPClientReceiveData;

  try
    HTTPClient.PreemptiveAuthentication := True;
    HTTPClient.CredentialsStorage.AddCredential(TCredentialsStorage.TCredential.Create(TAuthTargetType.Server, '', FEndpoint, 'username', 'password'));
    HTTPClient.Get(FEndpoint, MSImage);

    repeat
      FTerminateEvent.WaitFor(100);
    until Terminated;

  finally
    MSImage.Clear;
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is no point in using asynchronous request from background thread. You can use `TNetHTTPClient` asynchronously from the main thread and just cancel the request when application is closing or on any other appropriate user action. But to do that you need to use `TNetHTTPRequest` as you can call `Cancel` on the request associated with the `TNetHTTPClient` and you call `Get`  on the request and not on the client.

Comment: Another option is to run everything synchronously in the background thread, and again call the Cancel on the request. But in that case you will need to wait for the thread to finish in order to cleanup and you don't need any loop in the thread as Get request will return once it is canceled and thread will complete running on its own.

Comment: But, your main problem is probably somewhere else, as continuous stream will trigger `OnReceiveData` soon enough, you are just not waiting long enough for that to happen. and the actual problem is in your cleanup code that is not shown in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much @DalijaPrasnikar. Using TNetHTTPRequest solves the problem. For others who are not familiar with this component, you create the request object and the TNetHTTPClient object, assign the client to the Client property of the request object, and then call the Cancel method of the request object to terminate the get.

Comment: If you solved the problem, you can freely answer your own question and post your code solution in answer section.